# Content size issue for UITableView in UIscrollView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, interface-builder, scrollview, contentsize

I actually create a `UIScrollView` with a `UITableView` inside it with interface builder. I set the content size of my `UIScrollView` with:

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
```

and I set my file's owner view to the `UIScrollView`

I created an `IBOutlet` `UITableView` and I set it in the interface builder.

When the view is loaded. it displays the correct content size for my `UIScrollView`. But it doesn't display the correct content size for my `UITableView`. Besides when I change the content size of my `UIScrollView`, it changes the content size of my `UITableView` as if both content size were related.

Anyone knows how can I keep the content size of my table view that I set in the interface builder?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A `UITableView` is a `UIScrollView`. There are very few times when it would be useful to embed a `UITableView` inside a `UIScrollView`.

Assuming you really do want this, you'll need to do the following somewhere. Probably in your `UIViewController` in methods like `viewDidAppear:` or somewhere you after you populate the table view.

```
// Set the size of your table to be the size of it's contents 
// (since the outer scroll view will handle the scrolling).
CGRect tableFrame = tableView.frame;
tableFrame.size.height = tableView.contentSize.height;
tableFrame.size.width = tableView.contentSize.width; // if you would allow horiz scrolling
tableView.frame = tableFrame;

// Set the content size of your scroll view to be the content size of your 
// table view + whatever else you have in the scroll view.
// For the purposes of this example, I'm assuming the table view is in there alone.
scrollView.contentSize = tableView.contentSize;
```

Comment: It still doesn't work... Actually when I NSLog tableView.frame it displays me (null). I don't understand...

Comment: Actually, my file's owner is delegate of UIScrollView and UITableView which is a scrollView. Is it a problem?

Comment: I should have been more explicit. `tableView` and `scrollView` are supposed to be the IBOutlets you have associated with those items.

Comment: Yes, my IBOutlets tableView and scrollview are associated to my file's owner.

Comment: Your NSLog might just be having trouble trying to print a CGRect. is the tableView null? Also, where are you putting the code to re-size the table?

Comment: `NSLog(@"table view %@",tableView);   
NSLog(@"frame %@",tableView.frame);   
> table view <UITableView: 0x1099c00; frame = (0 397; 320 250);  clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x45a5b0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>  
> frame (null)`

Comment: It such weird... It says me that my tableView exist with an existing frame but when I try to display this frame it says (null)

Comment: That's because you are trying to print the contents of a struct as a string. You can print out an object because it just calls the `description` method on the object, but a struct has no such capability

Comment: This solution finally worked for me only after being used inside an observer for "contentSize" of the tableView, initiated in viewDidLoad(): `tableView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentSize", options:NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, context: nil)`

Answer (score 1):

Example to dynamically manage the TableView Height along with ScrollView, works in Swift:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        // Custom Cell
        let cell:TblPortCell = self.tableList.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! TblPortCell

        //tableList is the OutLet for the table
        tableList.sizeToFit()
        // Set the size of the table to be the size of it's contents
        // (since the outer scroll view will handle the scrolling).
        let height = tableList.frame.size.height
        let pos = tableList.frame.origin.y
        let sizeOfContent = height + pos + 130
        //scrollView is the Outlet for the Scroll view
        scrollView.contentSize.height = sizeOfContent
        scrollView.sizeToFit()

        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
        return cell
    }
```

References to:

- [Setting the ContentSize for ScrollView based in TableView ContentSize.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8789210/content-size-issue-for-uitableview-in-uiscrollview/8789755#8789755)
- [You must use sizeToFit before using contentSize.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19046969/uitextview-content-size-different-in-ios7/19047167#19047167)

Answer (score 0):

If you're still having problems, try this without the need for a scrollView.

After playing around with DBD's example for awhile, I found that the frame and contentSize don't seem to be able to be set together like:

```
self.tableView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, scrollHeight);
self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(self.tableView.frame.origin.x,44,self.tableView.contentSize.width,self.tableView.contentSize.height);
```

The attempt was to set a max height of the frame but keep the ability to scroll though all of the content if there were a large number of cells.  This hack seems to work well and can be modified with more conditions if needed:

```
int cellCount = [YOURARRAY count];
CGFloat scrollHeight = cellCount*44+44;//for a cell with height of 44 and adding 44 if you have a toolbar at the bottom

self.tableView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, scrollHeight);//you can change the width and or let the .xib control the autoresizing

if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad && cellCount < 14)
{
    //here's were you can add more conditions if you're in landscape or portrait, but this handles 14 cells with a heightForHeaderInSection of 46 in landscape
    self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(self.tableView.frame.origin.x,44,self.tableView.contentSize.width,scrollHeight);
}
else if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone && cellCount < 7)
{
     //same as above but it's for the iPhone in portrait
     self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(self.tableView.frame.origin.x,44,self.tableView.contentSize.width,scrollHeight);
}
```

This works for sure.  You might need to adjust the autoresizingMask inside your .xib or in your code, but this hack is the only solution I found that takes care of all the different variables in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Call below method multiple times. Each time you call there will be more cells.

```
CGRect tableFrame = tableView.frame;
tableFrame.size.height = tableView.contentSize.height;
tableView.frame = tableFrame;

scrollView.contentSize = tableView.contentSize;
```