# IOS 7 table view content size issue

Tags: iphone, ios, ios7, tableview, contentsize

I have a an app in IOS 6. Now i am try to make it compatible with IOS 7.

I have a search bar controller. All works good in IOS 6. I have used UISearch Display Controller.

But in IOS 7 content size of table view not set correctly.

While i dont search any thing :

[image]

But if i search any anything  than click on list view and scroll i have this out put :

![enter image description here][2]

You can see the white space below.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView1 sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index {
if (title == UITableViewIndexSearch) {
            [tblData scrollRectToVisible:self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.frame animated:NO];
            return -1;
        }
}
```

[image]

Thanks for Help

Comment: After searching only the white space is coming or while launching the view itself coming?

Comment: @Ganapathy The white space is coming while searching. I have full Table view but while searching its content size becoming small

Comment: Are you using custom cell?

Comment: Refer:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19046969/uitextview-content-size-different-in-ios7/19047167#19047167. i have posted a solution there with a link. I think your problem is similar though in that case the issue is in TextView. You need to use sizeToFit method before using contentSize in iOS7.

Comment: @Ganapathy Yes i am using custom cell.

Comment: Click [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19069503/uisearchdisplaycontrollers-searchresultstableviews-contentsize-is-incorrect-b/19162257#19162257?newreg=6fca5dd742e84b65904aa4ab72265882")!

hope it will help you

Comment: It's exactly not the same issue but might give some headway http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8789210/content-size-issue-for-uitableview-in-uiscrollview/32821375#32821375

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned in the comment, you have a custom cell, maybe with custom layout and view hierarchy. Be sure to add views to the cell's `contentView` instead the cell, that is changed in iOS7.